# Template Literal as a function argument in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Given the example below:

```
type AllNames = 'andre' | 'willian' | 'pedro'
type HiNames = `Hi ${AllNames}`

const value: AllNames = 'andre'

const randomFunction = (prop: HiNames) => `${prop}, how are you?`

randomFunction(`Hi ${value}`)
```

VSCode is throwing the following error :
`Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"Hi andre" | "Hi willian" | "Hi pedro"'.`

Wouldn't `Hi ${value}` always evaluate to `Hi andre`?

How could I use a template literal as a function argument in Typescript? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "*Wouldn't Hi ${value} always evaluate to Hi andre?*" No, why would it?

Comment: @VLAZ Because of the `const value: AllNames = 'andre'`, right?

Comment: OK, I thought you meant "*type HiNames = `Hi ${AllNames}`*"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the function is called, TypeScript is automatically widening the type of the expression

```
`Hi ${value}`
```

to `string`.

You can fix it by using `as const` to prevent the widening:

```
randomFunction(`Hi ${value}` as const)
```

Answer (score 2):

You code will work if you add [as const](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

```js
type AllNames = 'andre' | 'willian' | 'pedro'
type HiNames = `Hi ${AllNames}`

const value: AllNames = 'andre'

const randomFunction = (prop: HiNames) => `${prop}, how are you?`

randomFunction(`Hi ${value}` as const)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggNnAcgQwLYQM5QLxQOTIB2AJgE4R5QA++A7gJYL1GU16RkD2eAUKJFAAS9FOiy4ABsKgASAN7wkaTAF8JPHgGNOhDMCgA3ZHACuEAFywEozDnxEyFANwbtu-aQedUAMROFNYHodOwAKMFJOMEthGwwAShwAPigJeQiolQAaKAALTlooZHIoEE4TAH51LR09KAAzf00ANWM7KXpZOSNTCDUirDc9F08Sbz8AoJ1QxoDWuHieIA)

Answer (score 2):

#### TS String Interpretation

Typescript allows you to declare string literal types based on templates, but it doesn't *interpret* a templated value as a literal.

Consider this simple example:

```
const a = `andre`  // type: "andre"
const b = `Hi ${a}`  // type: string
```

Typescript interprets the single string `"andre"` (even with backticks) as its literal value and assigns the type `a: "andre"`.  It then sees a template `"Hi ${a}"` and inserts `a: "andre"` into it.  It interprets this new variable as `b: string`, even though both the template and its parts are known literals.  You want typescript to understand the template and return the literal `"Hi andre"` but it just doesn't do that.

Any sort of string manipulation just returns `string`.

```
const c = a + a; // "andreandre" - type is string
const d = a.toLowerCase(); // "andre" - not Lowercase<"andre">, just string
const e = `${a}`; // "andre" - type is string
```

#### Asserting Templated Type

These string literal types are new and perhaps this behavior will change in the future.  But for now, if you want to compose a templated value then you need to assert its type.

As others have mentioned, you can use `as const` on on any templated string to get its literal value.

You can also create a helper function that applies a template type when composing a string.  Here we make an assertion inside the function so that we don't need to make an assertion when we call it.

```
const hi = <T extends string>(name: T): `Hi ${T}` => {
  return `Hi ${name}` as `Hi ${T}`;
}
```

Now this is ok:

```
randomFunction(hi(value));
```

Because hovering over the `hi` function call shows:

```
const hi: <"andre">(name: "andre") => "Hi andre"
```

And the literal value `"Hi andre"` that we get here is assignable to `HiNames`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/eweRBN)